# 3TB HD Slave suddenly disappears - Windows asks to start the HD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, gpt

I Have a 3TB Seagate HD - working as slave with some media files - in WINDOWS 10 - like videos and images for my work.

This HD is working well - no noise, no fail, no connection issues (it's on sata) - nothing!

In november - I had 2.5-2.8TB in data (98% of capacity) - and the velocity of the HD drops a lot - sometimes near to 0.  But - no other issue appears - files are open well, videos with almost 5GB are playing well. But - as a precaution - I start to move all files to others HD.

I moved 2TB - and the HD appears to be OK again - no more slow, normal velocity to all -then - MY MISTAKE - I stopped to move the files.

Yesterday - the HD is fine - working as usual - but - when I try to move an image with 100KB - I receive an error: "Nonexistent Device" - I open Windows Explorer - and the HD is there. Normal. I Open the HD - and its OK. I can read all, I can access folders, see files.. but When I try to move a file to another drive - same error: "Nonexistent Device"- If I try to rename a file - same error: "NonExistent Device".

I never had this problem. It's like my HD is only a "Cache".  All files are there. No lag to show - but - nothing is accessible.

When I restart the PC - the HD disappears.
It is no longer in Windows Explorer.

But Disk Management recognizes the HD. It's asking to "START THE HD" - and I need to choose between MBR or GPT mode.

[image: Disk Management]

> > > IF I DO THIS MY FILES WILL BE DELETED? <<<

DISKPART doesn't recognize the HD

RECUVA recognize-but with an error:
"It is not possible to determine the type of system file"

[image: RECUVA]

Any idea to fix this?

tks!!

Comment: I think your drive has failed. Can you mount it on another machine to test?

Comment: “IF I DO THIS MY FILES WILL BE DELETED?” - YES